# Executing terminal commands using java Runtime for mode based execution

Tags: java

I have installed a terminal client utility on my linux terminal that enables me to talk to an external remote device. How do i execute such stuff using the java runtime?

For example if i want to execute a query on a mongodb installation, I can open a terminal and move to the mongo client mode by executing the "mongo --port 27017" command and get connected to the mongo server and then execute the commands from the mongo client mode from the terminal window. How can i do this from java run time.

```
[akhilv@dc1devpavxsrv01 bin]$ ./mongo --port 27017
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.5
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:5000/test
rpset:PRIMARY> use quartz
switched to db quartz
rpset:PRIMARY> show collections
quartz__calendars
quartz__jobs
quartz__locks
quartz__triggers
system.indexes
rpset:PRIMARY>
rpset:PRIMARY> exit
bye
[akhilv@dc1devpavxsrv01 bin]$
```

The above is the actual stuff that I want to be doing from the Runtime. I first execute the command **./mongo --port 27017** from my raw terminal and i am moved into the mongo client mode. Then i execute the **use quartz, show collections**  etc, which are understood only by my mongo client mode.

I am trying to execute "use quartz" and "show collections" commands to he executed from the java code using the Runtime. I am not very specific about Runtime, but need to be using something within java as i cannot go for client libraries from mongo or any other vendors.

Please help

Comment: 1. It is very unlikely that you can, and 2. you don't tell anything about what this utility is really about. Link?

Comment: I have modified the original post with details.

Comment: Well, if it's for mongodb, why don't you just use the Java API instead of delegating that to a shell?

Comment: Using mongo is definitely working, but I do not have the luxury of using the libraries here. Thats the problem

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do that by forking external processes from java and capture its I/O channels. So basicly from java you would have to invoke shell command, campture and parse its output. See some details on `Process` class.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html

The most interesting methods for you are `waitFor()` `getInputStream()` and `getOutputStream()` 
This is very similar how android applications can use root access - the same way :)

Comment: Is it possible to execute multiple commands with the same ProcessBuilder, as my situation here is that the mongo commands can be understood by the runtime only if it is in mongo client mode.. which again i suppose means that all the commands has to be executed as part of the same process

Comment: As far as I can tell, you need to be in mongo console, so build proper process, run it and capture input and output. This will be a form of overlay on mongo console.